# Dereferencing node pointer in my C++ linked list implementation giving unexpected results

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm implementing an unordered linked list in C++ based on first principles. My (partially complete so far) implementation is:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    int m_data;
    Node *m_next;

public:
    Node(int data)
    {
        m_data = data;
        m_next = nullptr;
    }

    int getData() { return m_data; }
    void setData(int data) { m_data = data; }
    Node* getNext() { return m_next; }
    void setNext(Node *next) { m_next = next; }
};

class UnorderedList {
public:
    Node *m_head;

public:
    UnorderedList()
    {
        m_head = nullptr;
    }

    bool isEmpty() { return m_head == nullptr; }

    void appendToHead(int data)
    {
        Node temp = Node(data);
        temp.setNext(m_head);
        m_head = &temp;
    }

    void remove(int data);
    bool search(int data);
};

int main()
{
    UnorderedList list1;
    list1.appendToHead(32);
    list1.appendToHead(47);
    list1.appendToHead(90);
    std::cout << list1.m_head->getData() << '\n';
    std::cout << list1.m_head->getNext()->getData() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to correctly print the head of the list as '90', but the next line (i.e. getNext()->getData()) gets printed as a large random number (281314120). What is the reason for this?

Comment: Never store the address of an object with *automatic storage duration*. You did that in `UnorderedList::appendToHead` method, thus invoking Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void appendToHead(int data)
{
    Node temp = Node(data);
    temp.setNext(m_head);
    m_head = &temp;
}
```

Never store the address of an object with [*automatic storage duration*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). That object (in this case, `temp`) will cease to exist when `appendToHead` method completes.

You did that and invoked Undefined Behavior. You probably wanted to do:

```
void appendToHead(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    temp->setNext(m_head);
    m_head = temp;
}
```

You should also consider satisfying [The Rule Of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

Rather than raw pointers, additionally explore the use of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot @WhiZTiM! I upvoted but since my reputation is currently 13, it won't show :)

Comment: @AbhimanyuSahai, You are very much welcome. Don't worry, It will show when your rep eventually gets there. :-). You can however, mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.